# Weird Issue - Wordpress Multisite - Cannot Access subdomain's pages

Tags: multisite, errors, dashboard, user-access, subdomains

Good evening to everyone. I will try to describe my (weird) problem, as detailed as possible and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I had a multisite that worked great. My company asked me **to extract a sub-site** and install it as a new website (not multisite) in another domain. And still keep the old multisite. Let's say i needed a clone of a sub-site to a new domain.

So i did it through prime-mover plugin. Worked as charm to the new website. So here comes the BUT:

**The problem: In the initial multisite now, I CANNOT access the sub-menu of the cloned sub-site! I mean, I CANNOT access the pages, the posts, the media, nothing! Though I CAN access it's main Dashboard (of the cloned subdomain) ---- I get 502 Bad Gateway error**

And I CAN access everything on the main site, I CAN even access everything on another subsite that is there!

Here is is the logic:

**domain.com**

**-subsite1.domain.com -------- (the cloned)**

**-subsite2.domain.com -------- nothing happened here**

And of course All 3 sites are live up and running.

I provide images for help understanding the issue (and for the sake of my mind :) )

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Seems a riddle to me. I have enough experience with WP can't seem to understand what is going wrong.
Do you think files got deleted? Or any database changes? Should i restore it to where it was?

Any help would be much appreciated cause I have lost days on that...

Comment: Update #1: Files restore (in subdomain), didn't change the problem.

Comment: Update #2: Neither database restore changed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for even thinking the issue :)

Is was actually a hosting configuration issue. Even though I have checked with them many times.